# Criar query para retornar o menor valor possivel

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, sql-select

Boa noite.
Preciso fazer um relatorio de vendas agrupadas pelo periodo e pelo cartao. Mas nao sei como faço para dar entrada em uma loja e na horizontal dela aparecer os valores de cada cartao. Exemplo de como deve ser a saida:
Loja01, com 03 vendas(100 visa; 55 visa; 200 master) deve aparecer no relatorio da seguinte forma:

[image: Preciso dessa saida no BD]

Segue meu codigo atual no SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/26e74/1

OBS: BD PostgreSQL

Comment: Você quer que seja retornada uma linha para cada loja? Teria como editar a pergunta e dar uma formatada no exemplo, talvez uma imagem com o exemplo do resultado no layout parecido com uma tabela já ficaria mais fácil para o pessoal da comunidade entender o teu problema.

Comment: Adicionei a foto de como precisa ser a saida.
Estava pesquisando e vi que isso se trata de uma tabela dinamica ( nunca tinha feito uma), e vou precisar usar o crosstab, mas nao ta indo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É comum a utilização da extensão `tablefunc` com a função `crosstab` para gerar os resultados dessa forma. Uma outra alternativa é utilizar as funções json do postgres para geração dos resultados.

Pode ser gerado o json diretamente pelo postgres e depois utilizando os recursos da linguagem de programação do frontend disponibilizar os resultados em coluna:

```
with vendas as(
    select 
        t.nome as store_nome,
        c.nome as card_nome,
        sum(s.valor) as total_sale
    from sale s 
        inner join store t 
            on (t.id = s.store_id_fk)
        inner join credit_card c 
            on (c.id = s.credit_card_fk)
    where 
        data between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31' 
    group by 
        t.nome,
        c.nome 
)
select 
    store_nome,
    json_object_agg(card_nome,total_sale) as bandeiras
from vendas
group by store_nome


store_nome |                          bandeiras                           
------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
Loja 02    | { "AMEX" : 60, "DINERS" : 60, "MASTER" : 60, "VISA" : 60 }
Loja 01    | { "AMEX" : 150, "DINERS" : 80, "MASTER" : 50, "VISA" : 100 }
(2 registros)
```

Também podem ser retornados os dados pelo postgres já com os valores separados por coluna utilizando o operador `->`:

```
with vendas as(
    select 
        t.nome as store_nome,
        c.nome as card_nome,
        sum(s.valor) as total_sale
    from sale s 
        inner join store t 
            on (t.id = s.store_id_fk)
        inner join credit_card c 
            on (c.id = s.credit_card_fk)
    where 
        data between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31' 
    group by 
        t.nome,
        c.nome 
), vendas_por_loja as (
    select
        store_nome,
        sum(total_sale) as total
    from vendas
    group by store_nome
), vendas_por_bandeira as (
    select 
        store_nome,
        jsonb_object_agg(card_nome,total_sale) as bandeiras
    from
        vendas
    group by store_nome
)
select 
    vb.store_nome,
    vb.bandeiras->'AMEX' as amex,
    vb.bandeiras->'VISA' as visa,
    vb.bandeiras->'DINERS' as diners,
    vb.bandeiras->'MASTER' as master,
    vl.total
from vendas_por_bandeira vb
    inner join vendas_por_loja vl
        on (vb.store_nome=vl.store_nome);

    store_nome | amex | visa | diners | master | total 
------------+------+------+--------+--------+-------
Loja 02    | 60   | 60   | 60     | 60     |   240
Loja 01    | 150  | 100  | 80     | 50     |   380
(2 registros)
```

A função `json_object_agg` está disponível desde a versão 9.4 do postgres.

http://bender.io/2016/09/18/dynamic-pivot-tables-with-json-and-postgresql/
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: Em partes deu certo, o problema é que nao soma a linha toda. Pra dar um resultado total de linhas. Nunca usei essa função json_object_agg, como eu criaria uma coluna pra somar as linhas?

Comment: E uma outra duvida, se essa nao for uma aplicação web, a função json_object_agg ira funcionar normalmente?

Comment: Editei a resposta adicionando uma forma de retornar o total de cada loja. A função `json_object_agg` é um tipo de dados do postgres, então vai funcionar independente da linguagem. Citei sobre retornar o json e trabalhar no frontend, ou outro tipo de linguagem de programação, por talvez ser mais simples de manipular os dados. Mas você pode usar o último código que retorna no formato tradicional.

Comment: Assim, entendi. Ficou bem legal. Uma outra duvida como eu trabalho os campos nulos. Por exemplo se uma a Loja02 nao vendeu no cartao Master e Diners. Como faço pra atribuir zero, ao inves de aparecer null?
Tem uma clausula where pra isso? Ou algum outro procedimento?

Comment: Acredito que a função `coalesce` resolva. Ainda bem que ajudei, não esquece de pontuar a resposta :)